# Working with void* as fixed width records in STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a continuous buffer with N records, each W bytes wide. **Both** N and W are unknown at compile time. N*M is orders of 500mb. I want to use that in standard STL argorithms, such as sort() or nth_element(). I do have a comparator at hand. Is there any already-implemented way to do so?

So far I figured 2 ways:

1) Use an additional vector, filled with indices 0...N, sort it (using custom comparator) instead of data so it resembles data records in sorted order, then move data records around in compliance with that vector. Downsides: additional memory, additional difficulty to fix data records order, which is slightly non-trivial.

2) Create some custom iterator (which knows W) that will return some temporary "virtual" class instances resembling records, and overload swap() for that class so that it exchanges chunks of memory. Downsides: somewhat tricky, somewhat fragile (needs to follow some STL internals such as knowing swap() will be used).

Comment: In the end, my solution is as follows: I indeed created a custom iterator which returned "Proxy" class objects, containing a pointer to the record. I implemented swap(), and I also implemented an assignment constructor/operator. To get rid of numerous allocations in assignment when swap() was not called, I also implemented a single static buffer with an atomic lock (I determined that 1 buffer is enough in most cases). When the lock is free, the preallocated buffer is used. When its busy, memory is allocated as usual. In the end, the swap() + single buffer reduced allocs to 0 in typical usage.

Answer (score 4):

Your second option--writing a custom iterator--is a viable approach and works quite well.

You don't need to rely on `swap` being used:  you just need to overload the assignment operator of your proxy object that you return when the iterator is dereferenced.

(Note that in C++11, algorithms and functions that "swap" elements are required to use a `swap` function found via ADL.  It's still preferable to overload the assignment operator, though, especially if you are just moving arrays of bytes around.)

I don't know of a general implementation off the top of my head, but as a starting point you could take a look at [`stride_iterator`](http://cxxreflect.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2ab4aa208c09#cxxreflect%2fcore%2fiterator.hpp) from one of my libraries (near the bottom of the file).  It wraps an array of bytes and overrides the arithmetic operators to move the iterator by N bytes at a time, where N is known only at runtime.

Comment: If I don't swap(), then default swap will be used, which does t=x, x=y, y=t. This way, I will also need to support temporary storage in proxy, which seems to involve extra alloc of W bytes per swap, which is lots of allocs. On the other hand, if I override swap(), i can exchange records without these extra allocs.

Answer (score 2):

I'd pick the second approach, but by providing custom copy semantics, not with a custom `swap`. Make the iterator value type be a class that holds a `void*` member and with a copy constructor and assignment operators that copy the record pointed to by that member. This doesn't rely on any implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for option 2), but you don't actually need to overload `swap()` for your stub classes. You just need to:

- Create a "stub" class that are returned by the iterator
- Implement the default ctor which allocates a chunk of memory of width W
- Implement the copy ctor which allocates a chunk of memory of width W, and copies the input chunk of memory
- Overload assignment operator such that the chunk of memory is copied from one instance to another.

In this way, `swap()` will automatically work for your class.